# Getting full address of returned location from geo-autocomplete api

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, google-maps-api-3

if you are not familiar with google's geo-autocomplete plugin let me just explain how mine works, i have a text-box, when you type a location inside the text-box the auto-complete plugin gives you a dropdown list of places with similar names.  Upon selecting the place you want, the map is generated for you.

What i want is to get the full address of the returned location into a text-box.
During some research i did online i cam across the:

```
getPlace()
```

function and the property i want:

```
formatted_address
```

but my problem is this is my first time using google's 'geo-autocomplete' plugin so i have no idea how to use these functions correctly.  Please help me if you have ever implemented something similar.

This is my code:

```
<!-- Google Maps API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 
        jquery.autocomplete.js requires a minor modification for geo_autocomplete to work
        the following script includes the required mod
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geo-autocomplete/lib/jquery.autocomplete_geomod.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geo-autocomplete/geo_autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="geo-autocomplete/lib/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <!-- Google Maps API -->
<script type=text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dialog-form').hide();

            $('#btnCancel').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('#btnPostAlert').css('cursor', 'pointer');


            $('#btnCancel').click(function () {
                $('#dialog-form').hide();
                alert(place.name)
            });

            $('#btnPostAlert').click(function () {
                $('#dialog-form').show();
            });
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            $("#location").geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, {
                mapkey: 'ABQIAAAAbnvDoAoYOSW2iqoXiGTpYBTIx7cuHpcaq3fYV4NM0BaZl8OxDxS9pQpgJkMv0RxjVl6cDGhDNERjaQ',
                selectFirst: false,
                minChars: 3,
                cacheLength: 50,
                width: 300,
                scroll: true,
                scrollHeight: 330,
                details: $('#details'),

            }).result(function (_event, _data) {
                if (_data) map.fitBounds(_data.geometry.viewport);

            )};

        });


                });
</script>

Can you please check it out.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "geo-autocomplete plugin", but when you mean the [places-autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete), you must observe the `place_changed` event of the `autocomplete`-instance (which fires when the user selects a place from the dropdown).

Inside the callback you may access the `placesResult` by using `this.getPlace()`, `formatted_address` is (when available) a property of the `placeRsult`, so you may retrieve it by using `this.getPlace().formatted_address`

Sample-code:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var address = this.getPlace().formatted_address||'';
    alert(address);
  });
```

Comment: I updated my post, i tried what you said but it didn't work, i checked the console there were no errors, please check my code and tell me if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: as I said there is no geo_autocomplete-plugin available inside the google-maps-API, you should give an information about the used plugin.

Comment: The actual name of the plugin is Places Autocomplete but the name when i downloaded it was geo-autocomplete.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/downloads/detail?name=jquery.geo-autocomplete-2.1.1.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: The second argument passed to `.result()` in your code is placesResult, so you have to use `_data.formatted_address` inside `.result()` . However, this plugin has been last updated 3 years ago, is not compatible with current jQuery-versions, I wouldn't use this plugin.